# Az CLI to configure Azure Function App TLS/SSL "HTTPS Only" Setting

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-webapps, azure-configuration

I am trying to use Az Cli to configure an Azure Function TLS/SSL Binding to switch the "HTTPS Only" setting from Off to On, as depicted below.

[image]

All attempts appear to have failed so far, using either of the below commands.

```
az webapp config set -g test-poc -n r-egm-test-fc  --http20-enabled true

az functionapp config set -g test-poc -n r-egm-test-fc  --http20-enabled true
```

Any ideas on:

1. Which command I should be using?
2. What is the correct syntax required to achieve my desired goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some bit of digging around, I manage to find and successfully test the following as the right command:

```
az functionapp update -n 'r-egm-test-fc' -g 'test-poc' --set httpsOnly=true
```

Works like a charm !!